# Gestion package ftp

Tags: php, ftp, package

Actually i'm in internship and i must add features on a site web who as been implement by someone who have quit the company (So i can only ask help to you :D).

The back-end of this site web is implement in PHP (nice, i'm beginner in PHP)and is hosted on a FTP server. Actually i must implement a JWT authentification, so i need to install PHP-jwt package with vendor (It's what i understood)

> composer require firebase/php-jwt

I guess it's working as npm in node but i don't know where to enter this command line as there is no console in FileZilla.

Where should I enter this command line to install php-jwt package ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you want to develop on a live server? Though I wouldn't really recommend it, you can do it. I guess the easiest way is to install the package in your local computer and then copy/paste that project onto the live server. This blog has some interesting viewpoints: https://www.codeenigma.com/build/blog/do-you-really-need-composer-production . Though, I would really, really, really recommend you setup a local development environment. Then copy the live website to that environment and start working there. If you break stuff, it's only on your pc and the live website is still fine.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer, i think i'll install package in local then copy/paste. But i'm curious to know if it's possible to install directly package via FileZilla.

Comment: AFAIK, filezilla is a FTP client and nothing more, so you probably can't execute console commands and the like.